# Storing data locally , either in pList or local folder

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, plist

I have an restaurant type iOS application that requires constant connection with webservices  (ASIHTTPREQUEST and TouchXML).

Is there any method such that I can store all the information, e.g. restaurant name, category that the particular restaurant have, food item in each category ?

I've done some research and I believed that pList is one of the good way to approach.
Is there any other good methods to recommend so that the next time when I reopen my application I do not have to go to the web services again. I can just get the data from either pList or some pre-cache files?

Answer (score 0):

Storing information such as products I would recommend either `CoreData` or `NSMutableDictionary`. For information such as restaurant name and other personal data, `NSUserDefaults` would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

For storing such kind of information, `SQLite` is a good option.

Gives you alot of control on the information.

Just fire a query and get your data...